# How to match a pattern only when it is not used as a head?

Tags: pattern-matching

I am working on modifying a mathematical expression and need some assistance. I have the following equation:

```mathematica
-27 f + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n
```

I aim to replace occurrences of `f` with `f[n]`, but I want to apply this transformation selectively. Specifically, I aim to replace `f` only where it does not serve as a function head. That means I want to transform standalone instances of `f` into `f[n]` without altering `f` when it's followed by square brackets and arguments (like `f[1 + n]`, `f[2 + n]`, etc.).

Is there a method or function in Mathematica to help me achieve this selective replacement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
expr = -27 f + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n;

p = Position[expr, f, Heads -> False]
```

{{1, 1, 2}}

```
MapAt[f[n] &, expr, p]
```

-27 f[n] + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n

Answer (score 12):

This trick is often useful with `ReplaceAll`: if you want some things to remain unaffected, you add a trivial replacement rule for that case before the replacement rule you really want

```
-27  f + 27  f[1 + n] - 9  f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3  n /. {
  expr : _f :> expr,
  f -> f[n]
}
```

> -27 f[n] + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n

Comment: What does _f do here?

Comment: @faceclean `_f` is a pattern that matches expressions like `f[1 + n]` where `f` is the head.

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = -27 f + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n

expr /. f[a__] :> g[a] /. f -> f[n] /. g[a__] :> f[a]
```

---

*Result:*

> -27 f[n] + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = -27  f + 27  f[1 + n] - 9  f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3  n;
```

---

Another way using `Cases`:

```
vars = Union@Cases[#, s1_@s2_ | s3_Symbol, Depth@#] &@expr;

rules = # -> If[# === f, #[n], #] & /@ # &@vars;

expr /. rules

(*-27 f[n] + 27 f[1 + n] - 9 f[2 + n] + f[3 + n] == 1 + 3 n*)
```